# What is the difference between ".toBeCalled" and ".toHaveBeenCalled"?

Tags: jestjs

When should each of these methods be called, and why?

```
const spyStart = spyOn(el, 'func1');
expect(spyStart).toHaveBeenCalled();


const spyStart = spyOn(el, 'func1');
expect(spyStart).toBeCalled();
```

Comment: [*"**`.toHaveBeenCalled()`** Also under the alias: `.toBeCalled()`"*](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeencalled) - there's no difference.

Comment: Yes; you can see in the source code they're both the return value from the same matcher factory: https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/4a59daa8715bde6a1b085ff7f4140f3a337045aa/packages/expect/src/spyMatchers.ts#L1125, https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/4a59daa8715bde6a1b085ff7f4140f3a337045aa/packages/expect/src/spyMatchers.ts#L1128

Comment: The difference is that toHaveBeenCalled is more grammatically correct but takes 6 letters more to type. toHaveBeenCalled was inherited from Jasmine.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Actually [`.toBeCalled` is an alias to `.toHaveBeenCalled`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalled), so they do the same thing.

From the docs:

> .toHaveBeenCalled() Also under the alias: .toBeCalled()